# flutter appbar not supporting RTL

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm using appbar and I've added an Icon button in the leading.
by making the app RTL this button stays on the left and won't come right.

because app is multi language and should support RTL. all the parts works but the appbar doesn't.

// AppBar

```
appBar: AppBar(
        // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        elevation: 0.5,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: ValueListenableBuilder(
          valueListenable: globals.selectedBarIndex,
          builder: (context, value, Widget? child) {
            return Text(globals.navBarItems[globals.selectedBarIndex.value].text);
          },
        ),
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
          icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
            valueListenable: widget.advancedDrawerController,
            builder: (_, value, __) {
              return AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                child: Icon(
                  value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
                  key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must use the **Directionality** widget.
To use Directionality in the AppBar, see the following code:

```
 PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size(width, height),
        child: Directionality(
         // ----right or left---
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: AppBar(
            // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0.5,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: globals.selectedBarIndex,
              builder: (context, value, Widget? child) {
                return Text(globals.navBarItems[globals.selectedBarIndex.value].text);
              },
            ),
            leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
              icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
                valueListenable: widget.advancedDrawerController,
                builder: (_, value, __) {
                  return AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                    child: Icon(
                      value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
                      key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

To properly support RTL (Right-to-Left) in your app's AppBar and handle the positioning of the leading IconButton based on the text direction, you can use the Directionality widget. Here's an example of how you can modify your AppBar code.Please check this this below code

```
AppBar(
  elevation: 0.5,
  centerTitle: true,
  title: ValueListenableBuilder(
    valueListenable: globals.selectedBarIndex,
    builder: (context, value, Widget? child) {
      return Text(globals.navBarItems[globals.selectedBarIndex.value].text);
    },
  ),
  leading: Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl, // Set the text direction based on your app's language/locale
    child: IconButton(
      onPressed: _handleMenuButtonPressed,
      icon: ValueListenableBuilder<AdvancedDrawerValue>(
        valueListenable: widget.advancedDrawerController,
        builder: (_, value, __) {
          return AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            child: Icon(
              value.visible ? Icons.clear : Icons.menu,
              key: ValueKey<bool>(value.visible),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```